# Table not displaying the first record from database

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

When I add my first record into the database table, it doesn't show on the page where the records are displayed. But when I add the second record and on, they are displayed on the page except the first record that I entered.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY player_role DESC", $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<table>";
    echo"<tr><th><B>Player Name</B><Th><B>Role</B></TR>";
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $myrow['player_name']. "</td>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$myrow['player_role']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can you see the entry in the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Player Name and Role should not be inside `while()` loop.
2. **MOST IMPORTANT** Do not use mysql, it is deprecated. Instead use `mysqli`

Your code (changed)

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY player_role DESC");
echo "<table>";
echo"<tr><th><B>Player Name</B></th><th><B>Role</B></th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['player_name'].'</td><td>'.$row['player_role'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be caused by nested `while()` loop. No need to use nested `while()`. Use one `while()` instead. Example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY player_role DESC", $db);
echo "<table>";
echo"<tr><th><B>Player Name</B></th><th><B>Role</B></th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['player_name'].'</td><td>'.$row['player_role'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```